# Compare two csv files and append the new column with awk

Tags: csv, awk

I have two csv files

file1. csv example - column 15 -value - 0812710304015 which is column 10 in file2

```
M|xxxxxxx|xxxxxx|xxxxxx|xxxxxxxxx|H-SYD-AUAUD-003658-00000013-160606221243|123466789123456|1806||8800|MC-TCSSGK-0812710304015  0000001#M|182137|||0812710304015|04080010194MORTIER/VINCENT MR Fee Transaction               0812710304015  QF  TCSSGK                           15022602300045                                        0000000088000000000000000000000000000009010200MC50TCSSGKMORTIER/VINCENT MR Fee TransaRIMGR +00000000800                xxx N150301B000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
M|xxxxxx|xxxxx|xxxx|xxxxxx|H-SYD-AUAUD-003658-00000025-160606221243|xxxxxxxxx|1811||8800|MC-MKNUYE-0812710304016  0000002#M|104749|||0812710304016|04080010194WILLIAMS/JAY MR Fee Transaction                  0812710304016  QF  MKNUYE                           15022602300045                                        0000000088000000000000000000000000000009010200MC50MKNUYEWILLIAMS/JAY MR Fee TransactiRIMGR +00000000800                QFAUAUDP1       N150301B000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
M|xxxxxx|xxxxx|xxxx|xxxxxx|H-SYD-AUAUD-003658-00000025-160606221243|xxxxxxxxx|1811||8800|MC-MKNUYE-0812710304016  0000002#M|104749|||0812710304017|04080010194WILLIAMS/JAY MR Fee Transaction                  0812710304016  QF  MKNUYE                           15022602300045                                        0000000088000000000000000000000000000009010200MC50MKNUYEWILLIAMS/JAY MR Fee TransactiRIMGR +00000000800                QFAUAUDP1       N150301B000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

file2.csv example - column 10 - 0812710304015

```
APPROVED||BATCH|BSP HOT|SYD||||QFAUAUDP1|0812710304015|MORTIER/VINCENT MR Fee Transa|TCSSGK|02300045|xxxxxxxxx|182137|0618|0;Successful;M;xxxxxxxxx|104749|1118|0;H-SYD-xxxx-003658-0000|MC|||
APPROVED||BATCH|BSP HOT|SYD||||QFAUAUDP1|0812710304016|WILLIAMS/JAY MR Fee Transacti|MKNUYE|02300045|xxxxxxxxx|104749|1118|0;Sucessful;M;xxxxxxxxx|104749|1118|0;H-SYD-xxxx-003658-0000|MC|||
```

output expected

if record found

```
 file1 all | file2 1 st column
```

if record not found

```
file1 all columns | record not found
```

Approved is the first column of in file2.csv file

so far my code is

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk

BEGIN {FS = OFS= "|"}

   NR == FNR  {

        A[$2] = $0;
        print "value of a[$10]="A[$2];
        b[$1] = $1;
        print "value of b[$1]="b[$1];
        next
    }

   {
        print "I am still in first loop";
        print $15;
        if ($15 in A){  ---------> here i am not able to verify value of A . value is null
        print $15;
        }
        else {
                print "Iam here ";
                print "vaslue of a[$1]=" A[$1]; -- > the value is A is null
                print "value of $10 = " $10;
                 print $0;
   }
   }
   file2.csv file1.csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -x
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1 ;b[$10]=$10;print "value of $10 " $10;next;}
{
if($15 in b){
print $0,a[$17];
}
else
{print $0,"record not found";}}' ./file1.csv ./file2.csv
```

the above works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something a bit shorter:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}
     FNR==NR {data[$(NF-1)]=$1; next}
     {$NF=$(NF-1) in data ? data[$(NF-1)] : "Record not found"}
     1' f2 f1
```

That is, loop through the second file and store the data using the penultimate field as a key and the first one as the value.

Then, loop through the first file and set the last field to either the stored value or the string "Record not found".

With your data:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} FNR==NR {data[$(NF-1)]=$1; next} {$NF=$(NF-1) in data ? data[$(NF-1)] : "Record not found"}1' f2 f1
G||london|0812710304015|Declined
G||malsyia|0812710304017|Record not found
G||malsyia|0812710304016|APPROVED
```

Comment: thanks fedorqui. it works only when no record is found but when the record is there in both the files, its not updating the last column with the with the value from file2 first column ie Approved or Declined. can you please help how can i achieve that

Comment: @AbrarAhamed define "its not updating". You mean updating the original file? For your given input, it generates the desired output.

Comment: i mean the output is correct only for the records which are not present in file2  . for the records which are present the last column is not getting update with file2 first column

Comment: @AbrarAhamed what I am saying is that the code I wrote is based on the format and sample files you gave. And it works. If your files are different, edit your original question and provide a more representative sample.

Comment: i have updated the question with full records. please have a look. thank you

Comment: @AbrarAhamed take a look at [ask] because what happened yesterday was a complete loss of time.